# How can I write a database function with where in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I am changing a db function and I need to add a query for items matching their category id with any items from an array i give.

Example input:

```js
let categories = ['10272111', '165796011', '3760911', '9223372036854776000','3760901','7141123011']
```

Part of db function:

```sql
(case when brand is null then '' else 'AND ra.brand ILIKE ''%%'||brand||'%%''' end),
(case when category is null then '' else 'AND ra.root_category IN ('||category||')' end),
(case when asin is null then '' else 'AND ra.asin ILIKE ''%%'||asin||'%%''' end),
```

But I keep getting `malformed array literal: "AND ra.root_category IN ("` error and I can't find any resource for the right syntax.

Edit:
This is the definition at the top of the function:
`category text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],`

Comment: Are you calling this query from JavaScript or directly from Postgres?

Comment: From javascript with sequelize.

Comment: You should add the relevant JS code.  Just showing plain SQL won't get you an answer here.

Comment: I just want to learn the correct syntax of middle line of my sql. I am sending an array of id's and I want to get items with their id in it. Js code is irrelevant with my question.

Comment: You _can't_ do this from native SQL like this.  However, you can build a statement from JS and then bind an array of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

Function decleration: `category text DEFAULT NULL::text`

```
(case when category is null then '' else 'AND ra.root_category IN '||category end),
```

is the query and I am sending the array this way:

```js
let categories = "(" + id_list.map((id) => "'"+id"'") + ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

As a generic approach, use `= any` and a string of comma-separated values instead of `IN`.
First change the function declaration, change `category text[]` to `category text`.
Then change

```sql
(case when category is null then '' else 'AND ra.root_category IN ('||category||')' end)
```

to

```sql
(case when category is null then '' else 'AND ra.root_category = any(''{'||category||'}'')' end)
```

Finally in JS convert the categories array to a string, i.e. `.join(',')` the category array and pass the resulting string to the function.

Unrelated but as far as I see dynamic SQL is not needed. Try

```sql
AND (category is null OR ra.root_category = any('{'||category||'}'))
-- or the equivalent 
AND (category is null OR ra.root_category = any(string_to_array(category, ',')))
```